GET Journals returns many -ve and +ve same amounts
If I'm getting Journal entries I find there many insignificant/confusing entries against an account that has an actual for the month of say $50. There's journal entries for say -$100 and $100, then -$20 and $20, then $50. So it all balances just very messy and I don't know how to exclude them.
Thanks

When a transaction is edited in Xero, there is a journal to reverse the original transaction and then a new journal for the revised details.
You would group the journals by source id and the current position is the net value of all the journals. The most recent journal has the current details for the transaction in terms of date and account codes etc. Journals are strictly sequential so the highest journal is the most recent, you can also check the updated date

Awesome that's it!
